# Create a record for each record from another table and set the id to the field

Tags: database, postgresql, migration

I need to write a migration. There is a profile_details table and an account table. I need to create an record in profile_details for each record in the account table and set the profile_details_id field from the account table to any id from the profile_details table. It doesn't matter which id the account record will get, all records at the beginning will be the same, the main thing is that they are unique.

```
with profile as (
            INSERT INTO profile_details 
            (id, company_name, country_code, address)
            SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), '', '', ''
            from account    
            returning *
        )
        update account
            Set profile_details_id = profile.id
            FROM profile
```

This option does not work due to an error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UQ_1b48abd3c37e09aac8235b3cd22"
DETAIL:  Key (profile_details_id)=(0ee5ead1-c0f0-4cd3-ae60-a1b493b0d460) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

Comment: Could you post an example? What records are in `account` and what records would you expect to be created in `profile_details`?

Comment: @SebDieBln None. Records in profile_details are created empty and the only dependency on the account table is the number of records in it. The content of the account records does not interest me. I only need the number of entries in profile_details to be equal to the number in account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to switch your `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements:

- Assign a random UUID to each account and use `RETURNING` to get a list of the created UUIDs.
- Use those returned UUIDs to create new records in the `profile_details` table.

```
WITH new_uuids AS (
  UPDATE account
  SET profile_details_id = uuid_generate_v4()
  RETURNING profile_details_id
)

INSERT INTO profile_details(id, company_name, country_code, address)
SELECT
  profile_details_id, '', '', ''
FROM new_uuids
```